# simplexml_load_file and simplexml_load_string return the same data with different encoding

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

Trying to parse an UTF-8 RSS feed from an URL, i first tried this:

```
$flux = simplexml_load_file("https://mamanslouves.com/feed");
foreach($flux->channel->item as $Item){
        $title      = $Item->title;
        echo $title;
}
```

This code works, but titles containing accents (éèà) are converted to another charset.
It appears that the following code fix the problem:

```
$raw = file_get_contents("https://mamanslouves.com/feed");
$flux = simplexml_load_string($raw);
foreach($flux->channel->item as $Item){...}
```

I would like to understand why.

Comment: file_get_contents() is binary safe while simplexml_load_file() can do internal conversions.

Comment: @MarkusZeller can you explain what that means for this problem? Does `simplexml_load_file()` do "internal conversions"? Which and why? Isn't it fully UTF-8 compatible?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Do a `curl -vvv -i https://mamanslouves.com/feed` and you will see the "file" is served as `content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` while the feed itself contains `encoding="UTF-8"` which is a lie. https://pastebin.com/8MhAGYtv

Comment: @MarkusZeller Ah, I _did_ check the file, but with a normal browser. I first get 2 redirects, first to `www.mamanslouves.org/feed`, **note the domain**, and then to `www.mamanslouves.org/feed/`, and finally I get the download itself. The HTTP header for the latter was `Content-Type application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8`, so I was satified, but on closer inspection I see that the first redirect uses `content-type text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`. I didn't spot that. I can confirm that is this cause because using `simplexml_load_file("https://mamanslouves.org/feed/");` shows normal accented letters.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it seems more clear to me now.

Comment: I don't know who owns `mamanslouves.com`, but it is clearly sending out a wrong `charset` in the header. You could ask them to correct this? This was a nice problem to set my teeth in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the discussion, I had with MarkusZeller in the comments, I think the answer should contain 2 components.

First we need to look at the URL you're using. It is not the URL of the file you eventually download. A look in the network tab of the browser developer tools shows this:

[image]

First there are two permanent redirections (301) before the RSS feed itself is downloaded. Everything is `UTF-8` encoded, the XML, and even the file you download. The only thing that isn't `UTF-8` is the first redirect, it is `iso-8859-1` encoded. You can see this by inspecting the headers in the network tab.

Then we need to consider what `simplexml_load_file()` does. It needs to figure out the encoding of the file it downloads. There are many places it could get the encoding from: The HTTP headers of the redirects, the HTTP headers of the feed, or the XML content. It is now clear it uses the first thing it encounters: The HTTP header of the first redirect, which says `iso-8859-1`. So, what is really `UTF-8` is read as `iso-8859-1` and everything goes wrong from there. The misread characters are then converted to `UTF-8`, but that makes no sense, as you saw.

To prove that it is the wrong `charset` in the first redirect that messes things up you can get the feed without the redirections:

```
$flux = simplexml_load_file("https://mamanslouves.org/feed/");
foreach($flux->channel->item as $Item){
        $title = $Item->title;
        echo $title;
}
```

And this does return normal accented letters.

The reason that going through `file_get_contents()` does work is because this function doesn't care about the `charset`, it just gives you the binary data which is then later interpreted as a `UTF-8` string. Exactly as Markus said.